# Is there a way to use a number in pyparsing?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am using the python library PyParsing in python 3.8, and I am wondering if there is a way to parse numbers? Here is my current code:

```
from pyparsing import Word, alphas
getWordParse = Word(alphas)
```

`alphas` is only characters, would there be a way to use numbers as well?

Comment: I removed your `python-3x` tag because there is nothing specific to Python3 in your question. Python3 is the new `python`.

Answer (score 0):

Pyparsing provides several convenience constants for defining Word's:

```
alphas = "A-Z" + "a-z"
nums = "0-9"
alphanums = alphas + nums
alphas8bit = "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþ"
hexnums "0-9" + "A-F" + "a-f"
printables = any non-whitespace character
```

But these are all just strings, and you can define Words using string literals too:

```
word_of_even_digits = Word("02468", as_keyword=True)
word_of_even_digits.search_string("248 125 126 298 42 3.14159").as_list()
```

Prints:

```
[['248'], ['42']]
```

Pyparsing also includes some parsers for common expressions (like `integer`, `real`, `fnumber`, and `number`), which also include parse actions that will returned the parsed results as ints or floats, instead of just strs.

Here is a good "getting started" docs page: https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowToUsePyparsing.html

And here is the reference page on Word: https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyparsing.html?highlight=Word#pyparsing.Word

Visit the pyparsing wiki for more info at: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/wiki